# Could not add maven-camel-plugin to project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jboss, apache-camel

The camel-maven plugin or one of its components failed when running Maven project.

I don't have an Internet connection. Is there a way to install this plugin when offline?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How should it work? You can not get a file without any connection

Comment: Hello Jens. The thecnollogy guys installed a local intranet repository so adding it to my m2/settings.xml I can pull the .jars I need. But it doesn't seem to store the camel-maven plugin or one of its components.

Comment: This are very important informations. you should add this to your question. Also the log from maven.

Answer (score 1):

Maven needs to download its plugins from a Maven repository. The standard Maven repository is MavenCentral. You can also set up your own Maven repository with Nexus or Artifacty (which was e.g. done in our company) and transfer the artifacts from the internet to your internal repository. So at least your Nexus/Artifactory needs an internet connection.

Following your comment at the question: Your "technology guy" needs to make sure that either your intranet repository is connected to MavenCentral or, if this not possible or allowed, he needs to copy all relevant artifacts from MavenCentral to your intranet repository. Determining the whole set of necessary artifacts can be tedious.

Comment: Thank, JF. I'd rather set it up myself in my local machine with just the camel-maven plug in. If I just mount a virtual machine that already has all the required plugins installed on my intranet machine, wiil it do the trick?

Comment: I do not really understand what you are trying to do. You can install the camel-maven-plugin in your own local repository (on your computer), or you can download it from some Nexus/Artifactory. You cannot read it from someone else's local repository.

Comment: Ok, JF, I'll follow your advice, I'll try to manually install in my local computer the required plugin. But I cannot seem to find the way to do it in Windows, any advice would be very useful. Thanks!

Comment: You need to download the plugin and all its dependencies from MavenCentral and then use the `install:install-file` goal to install them into your local repository.

Comment: Ok, JF, I found the camel-maven plugin at this MavenCentral location:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel-maven-plugin

Sorry to bother you with the details, but since I'm new to Jboss I don't know the procedure to download the whole plugin and its dependencies...Could you tell how exactly download them? Thanks again!

Comment: There is no automated way to do this. If you do not have a Maven connected to MavenCentral it is very time-consuming. You can download the plugin, then look up in the pom.xml what the dependencies are, download them one by one, look into their pom, download all of their dependencies. Now you also have parent poms, which could also define dependencies etc. When you build with Maven, it will show you missing dependencies , but only one by one.